# Makefile for GoLang Cross Compilation

Tags: go, makefile

I'm trying to create a `Makefile` for cross compiling a go binary. As you can see below, there's a lot of repetition. I also don't like that I have to re-invoke `make` with the arguments, rather than it matching an existing target already. Is there a more idiomatic way of achieving what I am trying to do?

I tried using wildcard targets to deduplicate some logic, for example

```
windows-%: app.config
    make os=windows arch=$*
```

but whenever I try and run it with this (i.e. `make windows-arm64`), I get back

```
make: Nothing to be done for `windows-arm64'.
```

EDIT: updated `makefile` after @norbert's suggestions. I think the only remaining complication is having to re-invoke `make` from within the target

```
tags =
executable_base = app
executable_ext =

# go version prints, i.e.: go version go1.18.5 darwin/arm64
# so we can use that as an os-independent way to figure out our current os and arch
os_arch = $(word 4, $(shell go version))
os = $(word 1,$(subst /, ,$(os_arch)))
arch = $(word 2,$(subst /, ,$(os_arch)))


ifeq (${os}, windows)
    executable_ext = .exe
endif


supported_distributions := $(shell go tool dist list | grep -E 'linux|windows|darwin' | grep -E 'amd64|arm64|386')


.PHONY: build all $(supported_distributions)

$(supported_distributions): output_dir = dist/${os}/${arch}
$(supported_distributions):
    make build os=$(word 1,$(subst /, ,$@)) arch=$(word 2,$(subst /, ,$@)) output_dir=${output_dir}

build: output_dir = dist/${os}/${arch}
build: app.config
    GOOS=${os} GOARCH=${arch} go build -tags "${tags}" -o ${output_dir}/${executable_base}${executable_ext} main.go
ifneq (${output_dir},.)
    cp -n ocrunner.config ${output_dir}/ || true
endif

all: $(supported_distributions)

app.config:
    go run cli/main.go create_config
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an idiomatic way. Shorter might be possible

```
go tool dist list
```

Gets you all builds.

By now just looking for the first 2 lowercase characters of the OS in the list against the ${os}, look for the arch as indicated, and at least it becomes responsive to the changes in golang capabilities.

As for Darwin 386: That is probably your only exception (Don't know where you would hit that one though)

Comment: ah yea the `go tool dist list` into a target variable is a good idea, then I can just do `make linux/amd64`, etc. Thanks for the tip!  The `darwin/386` combination would come from running on MacOS High Sierra using default terminal. If you run `arch` you get back `i386`. The way I have the makefile working is if you run `make build` without any arguments, it should use the correct os and arch for your current machine

Comment: If it is for the current machine, then this might even be easier:

`go version`
Returns `go version go1.18 darwin/amd64`

Comment: another good idea, yea I can use $(word,..) to split that string and get the current os and arch

Comment: But if they only build on their own os for their own os: Just `go build` will do (I sort of doubt that you would overlook that, so your reasoning for this added make file complexity is not clear to me yet)

Comment: nope they can build for any os, the default if no other os/arch is specified would to be build for the current.